# How do I use proportional editing while face projecting?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

After a bit of research, I realize this result (the image below) of using both face project and proportional editing at the same time is intentional, but has anyone ever found a workaround for this?

To be clear, I wish to *only* face project the selected edges onto the sphere, while the rest of the edges follow behind like it would normally with proportional editing. But as it is right now, using face project and proportional editing at the same time causes *all* edges in the proportional editing radius to project onto the sphere.

If anyone could point to a workaround or an addon that allows the desired result, that would be greatly appreciated.

[image]